# Library to solve dense linear system with GMRES

Tags: fortran, lapack, preconditioning, dense-matrix, gmres

I have a fortran 90 code and I want to solve a dense linear system with GMRES. I would prefer the restarted GMRES with preconditioning. Is there some library that you know of that I could use? Now I am solving the system with  LU using `dgetrf` and `dgetrs` from LAPACK.

I want to add also that the matrix is square, with diagonal dominance and invertible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

PETSC might be a good option. Not super user friendly, but its good with lots of options.

Comment: thank you. I was actually looking for something already written for fortran but since I don't see any other answer I will try to find how to use fortran with petsc.